# PHP, Javascript, HTML

Tags: php, javascript, html

How to get option value in PHP?
And i want to redirect to the same page, if option is changed by using onClick() function.
Anybody please help me.

Comment: http://www.tizag.com/phpT/postget.php

Answer (score 1):

Javascript :

Use eleement_id.selectedIndex() function , It will give the selected option properties.

Comment: he said "option value" not text of selected option.

Answer (score 1):

.......

```
<select name="select" onchange="document.location.href='this-page-name.php?val=' + this.value">
  options....
</select>
```

You can get its value like this:

```
echo $_GET['val'];
```